# how to use toString in junit and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, tostring

I am new to Java and i encounter problem with implementing toString. can someone help me?
the toString return the package name and the calling class name instead the results intention.
i am using eclipse 3.7.2. 
in different place in the code i used toString and it return the proper results

my file is MyLibraryTest.java

```
    public void testToString(){
    setup();
    addItems();
    //assertEquals("Test: 2 books; 2 people.", ml.toString());
    String results = ml.toString();
    assertEquals("Test: 2 books; 2 people.", results);

}

    results = org.totalBeginner.tutorial.MyLibraryTest.testToString
```

i wonder what have i done wrong?

here is the code to setup()

```
        public void setup(){
    b1 = new Book("Book1");
    b2 = new Book("Book2");

    p1 = new Person();
    p2 = new Person();

    p1.setName("Fred");
    p2.setName("Sue");

    ml = new MyLibrary("test");

    }
```

and here is the code to addItems()

```
private void addItems() {
        ml.addBook(b1);
        ml.addBook(b2);
        ml.addPerson(p1);
        ml.addPerson(p2);
         }
```

here how i am implementing to toString()

public String toSrting(){
            //return this.getName() + ": " + this.getBooks().size() + " books; " +    this.getPeople().size() + " people. ";
            return "Test: 2 books; 2 people.";
        }

Comment: What is `ml`? How is it defined and initialized? What is its toString() method implementation?

Comment: can you show us the toString impl?

Comment: What does `ml.toString()` actually return at that point?

Comment: what is ml?  can you post your implementation of ml.toString()  If ml is not already a String, the default toString from Object return the complete name of the class plus the hashcode as you saw in your test.

Comment: here is the code for the setup()public void setup(){
  b1 = new Book("Book1");
  b2 = new Book("Book2");
  
  p1 = new Person();
  p2 = new Person();
  
  p1.setName("Fred");
  p2.setName("Sue");
  
  ml = new MyLibrary("test");
 
 }

Answer (score 2):

Because of typo you do not actually override [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method. Instead you defined toSrting method. As you see, order of characters *t* and *r* is swapped. That's the reason of unexpected output directly from `Object.toString`.